I'm experiencing issues sending an email with a PDF attachment using the Gmail API
I'm experiencing issues sending an email with a PDF attachment using the Gmail API.
When I attach files like txt, png, and jpeg, there are no issues. However, if I want to send files like pdf, docx, xlsx as attachments, I encounter problems and the API returns an error.
<cfscript>
    try {
        manager_id_ = manager_id_;
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM MANAGERS WHERE MANAGER_ID = :manager_id";
    
        tokenInfo = queryExecute(
            sql = sqlQuery,
            params = { manager_id: { value: manager_id_, cfsqltype: "cf_sql_integer" } },
            options = { datasource: "rugs_db", result="result" }
        );
    
        if (tokenInfo.recordCount > 0) {
            accessToken = tokenInfo.GMAIL_TOKEN;
            toEmail = "myemail@test.com";
            subject = "Ekli Dosyalarla Test Emaili";
            bodyText = "Bu, ColdFusion kullanarak Gmail API'si ile ekli dosyalarla gönderilen bir test emailidir.";
    
            attachment1FilePath = "C:/Sites/documents/test.txt";
            attachment1FileContent = fileReadBinary(attachment1FilePath);
            attachment1FileName = "test.txt";

            attachment2FilePath = "C:/Sites/documents//test2.txt";
            attachment2FileContent = fileReadBinary(attachment2FilePath);
            attachment2FileName = "test2.txt";

            attachment3FilePath = "C:/Sites/documents/test.pdf";
            attachment3FileContent = fileReadBinary(attachment3FilePath);
            attachment3FileName = "test.pdf";
    
            boundary = createUUID();
            mimeMessage = [
                "MIME-Version: 1.0",
                "to: " & toEmail,
                "subject: " & subject,
                "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=" & boundary,
                "",
                "--" & boundary,
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
                "Content-Disposition: inline",
                "",
                bodyText,
                "",
                "--" & boundary,
                "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=""" & attachment1FileName & """",
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
                "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""" & attachment1FileName & """",
                "",
                binaryEncode(attachment1FileContent, "base64"),
                "",
                "--" & boundary,
                "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=""" & attachment2FileName & """",
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
                "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""" & attachment2FileName & """",
                "",
                binaryEncode(attachment2FileContent, "base64"),
                "",
                "--" & boundary,
                "Content-Type: application/pdf; name=""" & attachment3FileName & """",
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
                "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""" & attachment3FileName & """",
                "",
                binaryEncode(attachment3FileContent, "base64"),
                "--" & boundary & "--"
            ];
            mimeText = arrayToList(mimeMessage, chr(13) & chr(10));
            rawMessage = toBase64(mimeText);

            emailMessage = {
                "raw": rawMessage
            };

            
            cfhttp(
                method = "POST",
                url = "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send",
                charset = "UTF-8",
                result = "sendEmailResponse",
                timeout = 60,
                throwOnError = "true",
                resolveURL = "true"
            ) {
                cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Authorization", value="Bearer " & accessToken);
                cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/json");
                cfhttpparam(type="body", value=serializeJSON(emailMessage));
            }
    
            writeOutput("Email gönderildi. Yanıt: " & sendEmailResponse.filecontent);   
        } else {
            writeOutput("Manager ID için kayıt bulunamadı.");
        }
    } catch (any e) {
        writeOutput("Hata: " & e.message & "<br>");
        writeOutput("Detay: " & e.detail & "<br>");
        if (isDefined("sendEmailResponse.statusCode")) {
            writeOutput("HTTP Durum Kodu: " & sendEmailResponse.statusCode & "<br>");
            writeOutput("Yanıt Başlıkları: " & serializeJSON(sendEmailResponse.responseHeader) & "<br>");
            writeOutput("Yanıt Gövdesi: " & sendEmailResponse.filecontent & "<br>");
        }
        writeDump(e);
    }
    </cfscript>

This works. But PDF attachment not working.
<cfscript>
    try {
        manager_id_ = manager_id_;
        sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM MANAGERS WHERE MANAGER_ID = :manager_id";
    
        tokenInfo = queryExecute(
            sql = sqlQuery,
            params = { manager_id: { value: manager_id_, cfsqltype: "cf_sql_integer" } },
            options = { datasource: "rugs_db", result="result" }
        );
    
        if (tokenInfo.recordCount > 0) {
            accessToken = tokenInfo.GMAIL_TOKEN;
            toEmail = "myemail@test.com";
            subject = "Ekli Dosyalarla Test Emaili";
            bodyText = "Bu, ColdFusion kullanarak Gmail API'si ile ekli dosyalarla gönderilen bir test emailidir.";
    
            attachment1FilePath = "C:/Sites/documents/test.txt";
            attachment1FileContent = fileReadBinary(attachment1FilePath);
            attachment1FileName = "test.txt";

            attachment2FilePath = "C:/Sites/documents//test2.txt";
            attachment2FileContent = fileReadBinary(attachment2FilePath);
            attachment2FileName = "test2.txt";
    
            boundary = createUUID();
            mimeMessage = [
                "MIME-Version: 1.0",
                "to: " & toEmail,
                "subject: " & subject,
                "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=" & boundary,
                "",
                "--" & boundary,
                "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8",
                "Content-Disposition: inline",
                "",
                bodyText,
                "",
                "--" & boundary,
                "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=""" & attachment1FileName & """",
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
                "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""" & attachment1FileName & """",
                "",
                binaryEncode(attachment1FileContent, "base64"),
                "",
                "--" & boundary,
                "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=""" & attachment2FileName & """",
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64",
                "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=""" & attachment2FileName & """",
                "",
                binaryEncode(attachment2FileContent, "base64"),
                "--" & boundary & "--"
            ];
            mimeText = arrayToList(mimeMessage, chr(13) & chr(10));
            rawMessage = toBase64(mimeText);

            emailMessage = {
                "raw": rawMessage
            };

            
            cfhttp(
                method = "POST",
                url = "https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/send",
                charset = "UTF-8",
                result = "sendEmailResponse",
                timeout = 60,
                throwOnError = "true",
                resolveURL = "true"
            ) {
                cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Authorization", value="Bearer " & accessToken);
                cfhttpparam(type="header", name="Content-Type", value="application/json");
                cfhttpparam(type="body", value=serializeJSON(emailMessage));
            }
    
            writeOutput("Email gönderildi. Yanıt: " & sendEmailResponse.filecontent);   
        } else {
            writeOutput("Manager ID için kayıt bulunamadı.");
        }
    } catch (any e) {
        writeOutput("Hata: " & e.message & "<br>");
        writeOutput("Detay: " & e.detail & "<br>");
        if (isDefined("sendEmailResponse.statusCode")) {
            writeOutput("HTTP Durum Kodu: " & sendEmailResponse.statusCode & "<br>");
            writeOutput("Yanıt Başlıkları: " & serializeJSON(sendEmailResponse.responseHeader) & "<br>");
            writeOutput("Yanıt Gövdesi: " & sendEmailResponse.filecontent & "<br>");
        }
        writeDump(e);
    }
    </cfscript>```


About I encounter problems and the API returns an error. and not working., can you provide the details of it?

Connection Failure: Status code unavailable
When I run the request on postman, it returns 200, meaning all parameters are correct. But we have problems when we send a request with cf.

When I send a small pdf file of 1 kb, the e-mail is sent because the json is short. If we want to send a pdf of 2-3 MB, the connection breaks and does not work.

Resolved with an AJAX post. An issue arose with the JSON data size due to the ColdFusion Java version. If anyone encounters this, keep this information for reference.
